# Tangent at one point cuts at another.

Tags: calculus

[image: question 7][image: my attempt]

I have tried using writing tangent at given point and passing it through the other , but then calculation is not leading me anywhere.

Comment: why question being downvoted??

Answer (score 1):

\begin{cases}
x_0^3+y_0^3=a^3\hspace{2cm}(1),\\
x_1^3+y_1^3=a^3\hspace{2cm}(2),\\
x_0^2x_1+y_0^2y_1=a^3\hspace{1.2cm}(3).
\end{cases}
from $\dfrac{(1)-(3)}{(1)-(2)}$ we have
$$\dfrac{x_0^2}{x_0^2+x_0x_1+x_1^2}=\dfrac{y_0^2}{y_0^2+y_0y_1+y_1^2}$$
or
$$\dfrac{x_1}{x_0}+\left(\dfrac{x_1}{x_0}\right)^2=\dfrac{y_1}{y_0}+\left(\dfrac{y_1}{y_0}\right)^2$$
and then
$$\left(\dfrac{x_1}{x_0}-\dfrac{y_1}{y_0}\right)\left(1+\dfrac{x_1}{x_0}+\dfrac{y_1}{y_0}\right)=0$$
we have $\dfrac{x_1}{x_0}\neq\dfrac{y_1}{y_0}$ and finally have the answer as well.